# Pandas: count variance in pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, variance

I use

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='domain', values='active_seconds', aggfunc=np.var)
```

to return variance
But I need to add argument `ddof=1` to function, because result is wrong.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda`:

```
aggfunc=lambda x: np.var(x, ddof=1)
```

Or use [`GroupBy.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.var.html) with default `ddof=1`:

```
aggfunc='var'
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.random.choice(list('def'),size=30), 
                   'domain':np.random.choice(list('abc'),size=30),
                   'active_seconds':np.random.randint(10,size=30)})

print (df.head())
  ID  active_seconds domain
0  e               1      c
1  e               7      b
2  d               1      b
3  d               4      b
4  e               0      b

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                     columns='domain', 
                     values='active_seconds', 
                     aggfunc=lambda x: np.var(x, ddof=1))
print (df1)
domain          a          b          c
ID                                     
d        8.333333   8.333333  10.000000
e        8.000000  11.300000  16.333333
f       19.000000   8.000000  24.500000

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='domain', values='active_seconds', aggfunc='var')
print (df1)
domain          a          b          c
ID                                     
d        8.333333   8.333333  10.000000
e        8.000000  11.300000  16.333333
f       19.000000   8.000000  24.500000
```